# Connecting to RDS Proxy from Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds-proxy

I have a lambda function, RDS database, and RDS Proxy endpoint for the aforementioned database all inside a VPC (default) on the same two private subnets. The lambda function is unable to connect to the Proxy endpoint and times out accordingly, but I am not sure why. They all use the same security group (default), as well, with inbound settings for All Traffic from the same SG and outbound settings to anything. Route table has just one record to local.

I had previously had a NAT Gateway configured for the VPC and the lambda was connecting to the proxy with no issues. I deleted the NAT Gateway and am now having problems. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey John, It is not clear what could be a reason for timeout from the information you gave. I suggest you to deploy an EC2 instance with the same configuration as your Lambda function in this case you will be able to test and debug your connection.

Comment: Hi Ilya - I actually solved the problem. It turns out it was an entirely different issue and I had to add a VPC interface endpoint for an entirely different service. Thanks for the help!